# How to use "is_unbalance" and "scale_pos_weight" parameters in LightGBM for a binary classification project that is unbalanced (80:20)

Tags: python, classification, lightgbm, imbalanced-data, boosting

I am currently having an imbalanced dataset as shown diagram below:
[image: Distribution of target feature]

Then, I use the 'is_unbalance' parameter by setting it to `True` when training the LightGBM model. Diagrams below show how I use this parameter.

**Example of using native API:**
[image: Example of sing native API]

**Example of using sckit-learnAPI:**
[image: Example of using sckit-learnAPI]

***My questions are:***

1. Is the way I apply the use of `is_unbalance` parameter correct?
2. How to use `scale_pos_weight` instead of `is_unbalance`?
3. Or I should balance the dataset using **SMOTE** techniques like **SMOTE-ENN** or **SMOTE+TOME**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

This answer might be good for you question about is_unbalance:
[Use of 'is_unbalance' parameter in Lightgbm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68738225/use-of-is-unbalance-parameter-in-lightgbm)

You're not necessarily using the is_unbalance incorrectly, but sample_pos_weight will provide you a better control of weights of minority and majority class.

At this link there is a good explanation about the scale_pos_weight use:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/243207/what-is-the-proper-usage-of-scale-pos-weight-in-xgboost-for-imbalanced-datasets

Basically, the scale_pos_weight allows to set a configurable weight for the minority class, as a target variable. A good discussion about this topic is here
https://discuss.xgboost.ai/t/how-does-scale-pos-weight-affect-probabilities/1790/4.

About the SMOTE, I can't provide you theoretical proof about it, but considering my experience, everytime I tried to use it to improve any model performance using SMOTE, it failed.

A better approach might be to decide carefully which metric must be optimized. Better metrics for unbalanced problems are f1-score and also recall. In general, AUC, and Accuracy will be a bad choice. Also the -micro and weighted metrics are good metrics to use as objective when searching for hyperparameters)

Machine Learning Mastery provides a good explanation and implementation code about micro, macro and weighted metrics:
https://machinelearningmastery.com/precision-recall-and-f-measure-for-imbalanced-classification/